# Magento CE PCI Compliance

Tags: payment-gateway

What are the steps that need to be taken to achieve PCI Compliance for Magento CE?

For example using Paypal website payments pro or sage pay direct in a store would help to achieve PCI compliance?

Comment: You have to encrypt all data in a "PCIish" way. To check for PCI compliance costs afaik a lot of money. Why do you want this? Use the EE :-)

Comment: If you want to avoid potential difficulties, use a hosted payment method instead. Like SagePay server or PayPal standard.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### There is no reason why CE cannot be PCI Compliant

It was always regarded as being PCI Compliant - *until EE came along, then EE needed another USP.* As long as you aren't storing CC details - there is no requirement for encryption of other data (customer name/address etc).

But bear in mind that PCI Compliance is as much an application side requirement as it is a set of rules and definitions for running your company and handling sensitive information.

#### SAQ

What level of compliance you fall in to will dictate what you need to do to ensure PCI Compliance. If SAQ (self assessment questionnaire) is suitable for your business size, then you can pass unaided with CE - when using an external payment method (such as those described).

Otherwise, above SAQ levels - you'll need a QSA anyway - and you're talking big money with professional assistance. The fact you are asking here probably stipulates you aren't in this boundary.

You would likely fall under **SAQ-D**

> **How do you accept payment cards?**
>
> A. Card-not-present (e-commerce or mail/telephone-order) merchants, all cardholder data functions outsourced. This would never apply to face-to-face merchants.
>
> B. Imprint-only merchants with no electronic cardholder data storage, or standalone, dial-out terminal merchants with no electronic cardholder data storage.
>
> C-VT. Merchants using only web-based virtual terminals, no electronic cardholder data storage.
>
> C. Merchants with payment application systems connected to the Internet, no electronic cardholder data storage.
>
> D. All other merchants not included in descriptions for SAQ types A through C above, and all service providers defined by a payment brand as eligible to complete an SAQ.

See https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/smb/what_to_secure.html

#### Merchant/Transaction Level

> 1. Merchants processing over 6 million Visa transactions annually (all channels) or Global merchants identified as Level 1 by any Visa region 2
> 2. Merchants processing 1 million to 6 million Visa transactions annually (all channels)
> 3. Merchants processing 20,000 to 1 million Visa e-commerce transactions annually
> 4. Merchants processing less than 20,000 Visa e-commerce transactions annually and all other merchants processing up to 1 million Visa transactions annually

See http://usa.visa.com/merchants/risk_management/cisp_merchants.html

---

What is important is to differentiate the merchant level and SAQ level. They are separate. You can be SAQ-D as a Level 2 merchant. In-fact, in most cases you can self-assess up to Level 2 when at level SAQ-D - as the requirements are more relaxed because you are not handling card data at all.

---

Merely using EE does not make you PCI Compliant, the same way using a PCI Compliant host doesn't make you PCI Compliant. Your business as a whole (application, business/staff, hosting) must all be PCI Compliant.

Answer (score 2):

The PCI level you need to comply with depends on how many transactions your are likely going to have. As a first step you should work out which level would apply to you:

1. Any merchant -- regardless of acceptance channel -- processing over
   6M Visa transactions per year. Any merchant that Visa, at its sole
   discretion, determines should meet the Level 1 merchant requirements
   to minimize risk to the Visa system.
2. Any merchant -- regardless of acceptance channel -- processing 1M to
   6M Visa transactions per year.
3. Any merchant processing 20,000 to 1M Visa e-commerce transactions
   per year.
4. Any merchant processing fewer than 20,000 Visa e-commerce
   transactions per year, and all other merchants -- regardless of
   acceptance channel -- processing up to 1M Visa transactions per
   year.

http://usa.visa.com/merchants/risk_management/cisp_merchants.html
this is from VISA but would similarly apply to PCI

With each level you will have different requirements to meet. Once you have done the assessment I am sure someone will be able to give you a more detailed answer on what steps to take with CE.

Answer (score 1):

[Enterprise Edition](http://www.magentocommerce.com/product/enterprise-edition) comes with an application called [Payment Bridge](http://www.magentocommerce.com/company/pci-compliance) which deals with a really nice amount of encryption and can be run on a separate server than your application. This can be over-kill for most contexts, and requires willingness to isolate and debug application code in a OO organization that isn't as easy to follow as the Magento Core code.

PCI compliance has many small nuances which actually do make CE not fully PCI compliant. The fastest and often best way to be PCI compliant on CE is to use a third party tokenization payment gateway system. There are a few extensions that already have integrated Authorize.net CIM, or Cybersource Payment Profiles, and a few others. This means that when implemented correctly, all you ever store is the profileID for the customer and the credit card data is stored on the payment gateway.

That being said, I don't think your question clearly states the information you're wishing to store about the transaction that you're looking to enhance to meet PCI compliance. Without more information it is difficult to help solve your particular requirement's architecture with any specificity.

Comment: Re: sonassi your answer is incorrect CE was considered PCI compliant until the PCI compliance rules change in 2010 and CE no longer fit the requirements.

Comment: The OP was pretty clear that they are not processing or storing any card holder information, they are relying on external services to capture and process payments. **Any** application can be PCI compliant, CE included, without any hard work so long as you are not actually storing card holder data. But PCI compliance isn't just the software you are using. Its all about company practices and implementation.

Comment: Nice vote down... I also said CE can be compliant... but is not out of the box, and yes biz process is important too, but I guess you don't give credit for good value in a response even if my viewpoint conflicts with yours and happens to discuss solutions to some of the problems should PCI compliance efforts be made which your response did not. I also saw no mention of Payment Bridge nor what Payment Bridge accomplishes toward PCI compliance in your response. And I stand by my statement... the assertion that CE's PCI compliance was there and never changed is a fallacy. the requirements changed

Comment: The OP never showed an interest in EE. This question is about CE. CE is not **PA-DSS** certified, but that is not the same as PCI compliant. Natively, you cannot store CC data in a PCI way with CE - but the OP never intended to.

Answer (score 0):

I think are normally two ways:

1. You don't want to do it yourself, because you are a small shop, then you should stay with the CE and use some payment provider to do this thinks for you
2. You are a big company and expect a lot of transactions and want to do it yourself. Then you should have enough money to use the EE.

**OLD ANSWER:**

You have to encrypt all credit card data (thanks to @sonassi) in a "PCIish" way, and a lot more. To check for PCI compliance costs afaik a lot of money. Why do you want this? Use the EE :-)

All the information you need can be found On the [PCI Website](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/security_standards/documents.php?agreements=pcidss&association=pcidss)

And I don't think there are much developers here, who know the standard, me neither.

PCI compliance is nothing to play with. If you want this, you have to spent a lot of money and you need experts.

Comment: You don't need to encrypt anything other than **Cardholder Details**.

Comment: I don't think an EE recommendation is ever warranted in an attempt to meet PCI Compliance - even if the OP were saving CC details (which they are not).

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins (e.g. security company Foregenix have one that does logging, file change monitoring and few other things) that can help put some of the PCI controls in place quickly and simply.  But if you're looking to take the easiest path from a compliance perspective you should really consider using a hosted payment page from your payment gateway.  This will allow you to use SAQ A-EP (as long as you're not trying to do something different from the ordinary hosted payment page).